# Cannot install Xamarin.Android.Support.v4

Tags: android, xamarin, nuget, package

I am trying to install this particular package into my program and get the following error:

> Error     Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat
>   24.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain
>   any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

What exactly is my project suppost to target and how do I make this change? I already installed android 7, however I cannot even target that for some strange reason. Not even if I make a new project I can't target that.

Answer (score 10):

This package requires `MonoAndroid70` to be installed. Thus you need to ensure your `TargetFrameworkVersion` is set to a minimum of Android 7.0. You will need to install API 24(7.0) and change the version.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/#framework

For those interested in how you would find this, you can download the `.nupkg` from NuGet:

https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4/24.2.1

You can then extract the `.nupkg` and view the `lib` folder which will show you what the library supports.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend below steps

1- download a previous version (

```
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.1.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
```

)

2- delete the following local folder "..\AppData\Local\Xamarin"

3- Build the droid project (it will take some times)

Finally, no more issues with these xamarin support packages.

Cheers UP!

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

- Try to update your xamarin visual Studio after you will install it and you will get monoandroid v7
- update your android sdk Api 24 or api 25

I think it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I removed from the Android SDK all API dependencies 23, ie Android 6.0 and installed from 7.0 and 7.1 (AP 24 and 25).

**Clean and Rebuild** the project.

Done that, it worked correctly.
Hope this helps.