# Xamarin update project to SDK 24

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Android project that is about two years old. I am wanting to update the project to support Android API level 24, and have set the "Target SDK" in the options pane to said level. I also need to use version 24.2.1 of the Android Support Library in order to support run-time permissions. I am currently using version 22.2.1 of the support library. This does not apparently include run-time permission checking.

I have tried to update the support library to version 24.2.1 using the normal method by right-clicking on the package and choosing update. However, when I do this I get the following error.

```
Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 24.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v4.4', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

I have ensured that all shared projects and libraries I am using in my project are set to use the latest SDK available which is version 7.0 (API 24). Again, I have ensured that the target SDK version in my project is set to version 7.0 (API 24). However, if I set the "automatic" version option then Xamarin tells me the version is 4.4 (API 19).

After spending hours looking through every package, reference and component in my project, it's a rather large one, I've found that the Mono.Android version says it support Android 4.4. I'm thinking this must be the culprit that is preventing my project from being compiled with the version 7.0 SDK. (Please see screenshot below).

[image]

I went ahead and made a brand new project using the normal "Add Project" method in Xamarin, and when I did it showed the following.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot the newer test project shows it supports v7.0, and when I set the automatic target in my options pane it correctly says Android 7.0 (API 24). Also, I'm able to import the Android Support Library v4 version 24.2.1 in the project.

I suppose my question here is has anyone ever had this issue before and found as solution other than making a brand new project and moving all code files over? Is there a way to update the Mono.Android package? I do not see a way todo that within the package manager or the reference menu.

Comment: You are confusing `Target SDK` with `TargetFrameworkVersion`. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40308329/cannot-install-xamarin-android-support-v4/40309184#40309184 Feel free to overlook this blog to see the differences: http://redth.codes/such-android-api-levels-much-confuse-wow/

Comment: ah, gotcha. I can't believe I didn't see that option. Anyways, that fixed my issue. Please add your above comment as an answer so I can accept it. Got to get your points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing `Target SDK Version` with `TargetFrameworkVersion`. This package requires `MonoAndroid70` to be installed. Thus you need to ensure your `TargetFrameworkVersion` is set to a minimum of Android 7.0. If you don't have API 24 installed, you will need to install API 24(7.0) and change the version in your project.

**Resources:**

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/#framework

http://redth.codes/such-android-api-levels-much-confuse-wow/