# Xamarin.Support.v7.RecyclerView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Hi I'm trying to install via nuget Xamarin.Support.V7.RecyclerView however I'm getting the following error :

> "Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView
>   25.1.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain
>   any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.   "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install Xamarin.Android.Support.v4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40308329/cannot-install-xamarin-android-support-v4)

Answer (score 0):

i think this it will help you.

1. try to update or download new version xamarin visual studio it will give you monoandroid v7 to be worked and set your Droid TargetFrameworkVersion to Android 7.0 or bigger.
   Xamarin new version go www.https://www.xamarin.com/ -> login -> Profile -> Dashboard -> Download
2. try to update android sdk Android 7.1.1(API 25)

After all done install again Xamarin.Support.V7.RecyclerView, it will work