# Xamarin can not install NuGet packages: profile 259 error

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget

I am developing a cross-platform Xamarin app. When I install new packages using the NuGet package manager, the console shows this error:

> Could not install package 'X' You are trying to install this package
>   into a project that the target .NetPortable, Version=4.5, Profile=259
>   but the package does not contains any assembly references

I know that Profile 259 is generally used for WP or Silverlight based packages. I tried to change configurations on the *Properties → Library → Change* tab, but this time the system shows:

> Project target cannot to be changed.The selected target require
>   nuget 3.0

How can I solve this problem?

Here's the [image of the last error message dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZyeg.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the NuGet definition for this item:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost/

It only supports `net45`. Thus it cannot install into `Profile259`.

To be able to install to `Profile259` it would need to have a target framework of `portable-net45+win8+wpa81+wp8` or `netstandard1.0`.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your relevance to question Jon. I know that my packages.config files references setted this configuration for example => <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.4.0.282" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" /> , but i get error again my problem is not solved.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. You can view my other answer on [how to download and extract a `.nupkg` to view the Target Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40308329/cannot-install-xamarin-android-support-v4/40309184#40309184). You can view all target frameworks here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/target-frameworks

Comment: I changed to framework version then uncheck some of targets finally packages working well thanks for your help Dear Jon.